# Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for measures

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis

Riemann Lebesgue Lemma states that Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function, $\hat{f}(\lambda)$ is continuous and goes to zero as $|\lambda|\to \infty$. If $\mu$ is a finite nonatomic measure then is it  true that $\hat{\mu}(\lambda)\to 0$?  If not then is it true for some restricted class of finite measures? What are the restrictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following web site has a review article on work related to this question:
http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/pdf/seventy.pdf

Comment: 
Comment just for those skimming this page without reading the link: the established jargon for such a measure is a *Rajchman measure*